Microsoft Graph API hangs indefinitely when called from Swagger API Service
I am running into a very odd issue the following call to Microsoft's Graph API hangs indefinitely, never finishing. This only happens when the process is invoked from a Swagger.
When called from Tests or anything else code works fine...
The code that is hanging up is below:
var usersResponse = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
{ 
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "accountEnabled eq true";
});

I have tried changing how I call the GetAsync method Synchronously - I have also tried the following, but the same issue persists:
var usersResponse = graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
{
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "accountEnabled eq true";
}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

What can I do to avoid/fix this issue? I'd like to avoid completely refactoring again to use something other than a Swagger service invocation.
EDIT: A reproduceable sample of code is below, can confirm this is hanging for me when debugging locally:
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/CoreUserController/RunUserSyncTest")]
public void RunUserSyncTest()
{
    string tenantId = "My Tenant Id";
    string clientId = "My Client Id";
    string clientSecret = "My Client Secret";
    string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions options = new Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };
    Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
    Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

    var usersResponse = graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "accountEnabled eq true";
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}


Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? You have a lot of information here that is very specific to your problem... My best guess is that your code is never called... Also when called from swagger...? Meaning the code works if called from elsewhere?

@panoskarajohn The post has been commented to include reproduceable code. And yes, as mentioned in the ticket the code works when called from tests or when debugging, it only hangs when invocating the Swagger service.

I've tried the same method and everything works fine. Could you share more code? Probably the whole controller and how do you configure swagger. What do you mean by Swagger service?

What version of the Graph SDK are you using?
